# How to modify "/etc/bash.bashrc"? It is read only?

Tags: bash, command-line, bashrc

Trying to modify `/etc/bash.bashrc` I get an error:

```
$ echo "my edit" >> /etc/bash.bashrc
bash: /etc/bash.bashrc: Permission denied
```

`ls -ll /etc/bash.bashrc` shows:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1975 2011-05-18 19:54 /etc/bash.bashrc
```

How could I modify `/etc/bash.bashrc` ?

Comment: Also, you know you can just edit ~/.bashrc?  You probably do, but just making sure. lol

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/82256/how-do-i-use-sudo-to-redirect-output-to-a-location-i-dont-have-permission-to-wr

Comment: `sudo $EDITOR /etc/bashrc`. You can set *$EDITOR* in your *.bashrc* as well (with - e.g. -  `export EDITOR=vim`). Or you can simply run (e.g.) `sudo atom /etc/bashrc` which will use the atom editor, or you can replace "atom" with whatever.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need superuser permissions to edit the file.

To become the superuser, type in `sudo -s` then enter your password. After you log in, then try your command, and it will work.

Comment: `sudo chmod 777 /etc/bash.bashrc`: **Terrible** idea.

Comment: They asked, I answered.

Comment: *No one* asked you how to create system-wide security holes. That was your own suggestion. The responsible thing for you to do would have been to explain how to modify the contents of the file in accordance with Ubuntu's [documented best practices for privilege elevation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo).

Comment: I have edited my answer.

Comment: Can't see *any* reason on chmod'ing a `/etc/bash.bashrc`.

Comment: @AndrejsCainikovs,some people have computers that they are the sole user. So permissions don't really matter that much to us [me being one of them].

Comment: @Matt, the fact is that even after `chown`, this file will still be readable by others because of 644 permission. Hence it makes no sense at all.

Comment: @AndrejsCainikovs, after `chown` the user can edit the file without a password, hence making sense?

Comment: Well, this is leading to a dead end. While you are trying to give a direct answer to the incorrect question, I'm trying to explain author that he is going wrong way.

Comment: @AndrejsCainikovs happy now?

Comment: Yes, Matt :) +1'd.

Answer (score 8):

```
sudo bash -c "echo 'text' >> /etc/bashrc"
```

Don't change the owner. Don't chmod it. Just use sudo. Open it with sudoedit if you need to do complicated things.

By the way, you can make changes for one user by just editing ~/.bashrc without requiring any special permissions.

Comment: Clean and mean.

Comment: `su -c "echo 'text'" >> /etc/bashrc` ^.^

Answer (score 3):

You've probably discovered by now that there are many ways to do this. But I think this one is the most elegant of all. (It often involves the least typing, too, when everything is said and done.)

```
echo "my edit" | sudo tee -a /etc/bash.bashrc
```

See [`man tee`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/tee.1.html) if you're interested in the technical details of how this works.

In general:

- To do the work of `echo some-text > some-file` as `root`, run:

  ```
  echo some-text | sudo tee some-file
  ```
- To do the work of `echo some-text >> some-file` as `root`, run:

  ```
  echo some-text | sudo tee -a some-file
  ```

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo nano /etc/bash.bashrc
```

Do the changes you want. Save it (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>) and confirm with `y` and <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Answer (score -3):

```
sudo echo "my edit" >> /etc/bash.bashrc
```

Comment: This does not work.  You are `echo`ing as root.. but the **regular** user is doing the appending.